# Programatically changing hash of a file without corrupting it

Tags: php, hash

Does anyone have any info on changing the hash of a file without corrupting it?

I read about appending a null byte to the end of the file, thus changing the MD5 without corrupting it. Anyone have any info?

The language I wish to do this in is PHP.

Thanks.

Comment: accept some answers

Comment: What hash (MD5?) are you talking about? Why do you need this?

Comment: Yeah, MD5. I need it because the guy who hosts my webserver wants to delete dupe files and that's how he's checking them. I just want to act against it. :)

Comment: Are you actually *paying* for this hosting? Do you have a limit on storage that you are currently not exceeding? If so, your host should have zero right to delete your files.

Comment: Don't be so quick to judge. My server has a 500GB hard drive, and I own the entire box. The person who I'm renting it from says he will prune all dupe files to save HDD space. The HDD is ~85% full, and I'm allowed to use 100% of it if I wanted. He's the one in the wrong, not me.

Comment: Simple solution: get a different hosting provider.

Comment: I wasn't judging *you*, Joseph, more judging your provider. Why is he even contemplating saving disk space when you're well under capacity? I agree with you that he's in the wrong.

Comment: Just tell him "Hey, im paying all my 500GB, lets me use them as i prefer. If i would, i could even fill it up with garbage."

He doesnt have any rights on what you do with your space.

Comment: ....and why so many downvotes?

Comment: I'm not sure, so i'm not posting this as answer
change BOM of a file, may work. at least for ascii ones.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on exactly what the applications expect when they read this file. If, for example, it's a text file, you could simply insert a space following one of the paragraphs. This doesn't change the readability of the file by humans but it will change the MD5.

Likewise for basic HTML files or source files such as C or PHP where the spacing doesn't matter (as long as you insert the space in a syntactically insignificant area, so not inside string constants for example) . Put in some extra spaces or add newline characters at the end and you'll find the behavior of your web pages doesn't change.

However this is unlikely to work for an executable file since it will probably crash and burn when you run it (if indeed it even loads - some loaders may use checksums for the load sections).

You need to specify exactly what corruption means in the case you're talking about.

*Update:*

For example, in JPEG files, it's probably a simple matter of replacing the EOI marker at the end with a unique COM section followed by an EOI marker. The EOI marker is the end of image and you should be able to insert the comment section (with a unique comment) before it. This would make each JPEG have a different MD5 while stil presenting the same image. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG).

With ZIP files, you can actually insert arbitrary data in between each file since the catalog at the end lists files with their offsets. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29) for details. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with the internals of RAR files.

Comment: Sorry, most of the files are .ZIP and .RAR, with some .jpegs.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you might be better off just changing those duplicate files to symbolic links `ln -s otherfolder/file file` (assuming the server is on a *nix platform).

Answer (score 1):

If you are primarily dealing with .ZIP and .RAR files, find a ZIP/RAR library for PHP, and simply add a tiny random file to every zip/rar.

For JPEGs, follow [paxdiablo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14860/paxdiablo)'s answer.