# Changing CRC of a file through readfile()

Tags: php, readfile

I have this code set up that lets a user download a file through my server from a URL they specify. The file streams through using readfile() so it only uses my bandwidth.

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);

$urlParts = explode("/", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$file = $urlParts[3];

header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: hack");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $file);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");
readfile($file);

?>
```

This script works, but it does not change the CRC hash of the downloaded file. What I want it to do is append some random bits to the end of the file so it can change the hash without corrupting it. I have tried adding something like `echo md5(rand() . time());` to the end of the script but it doesn't work.

If this is possible with something like cURL I'd appreciate if someone could put up some code samples, because i'd switch to cURL if this was possible.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Similar to SO question `programatically-changing-hash-of-a-file-without-corrupting-it` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895251/programatically-changing-hash-of-a-file-without-corrupting-it)

Comment: Your goal is unclear.  Do you wish to add a few bytes at then end of the http response (hence making the hash computed, _on the receiving end_), or do you want to alter the file itself, on the server side, so that its hash is changed (so for example a future download would see the file different).  In fact providing insight into the actual use case (WHY does the hash needs to be different) would be useful and may prompt contributors to suggest alternative approaches as well.

Comment: It's you escape the blacklist some of my clients have installed on their networks, the system does a CRC check of the files and if they're the same after the download they get automatically deleted. I originally thought adding a few bytes to the end of the file would be the way to do it, but if you just send a few bytes and end the http response and that works I'd rather do it that way. On another note, could I use a combination of fopen() and print? That would send the file to the browser so many bits at a time, and after I reach EOF I could add a few more bits?

Comment: In what way does echo md5(rand() . time()) not work? It *should* work, as readfile() does not read the EOF, too.

Comment: I checked the original file and the file I downloaded through this script, and they had all the same hashes (checked with md5, sha1).

Comment: zip or rar or tar the file. that would definitely change the crc :P

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option :/

Comment: +1 for Lukman, very good idea. Andy: make sure your browser is not caching the download. I just made a test and `echo` after readfile() works. Also, is that code your **whole** code? If not, and you are also sending a `Content-Length` header (deducted from the file's size), the client will ignore anything after that number of bytes.

Comment: Ah, Felix! It could be the content-length. It's getting it from the original file every time so that would make sense. In regards to the caching, I made it re-validate. :) I'll test out the content-length theory now, thanks.

Comment: Brilliant Felix, it works a charm without the Content-Header. Thank you _very_ much :)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, your code works for me:

**test.php:**

```
set_time_limit(0);

$urlParts = explode("/", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
//$file = $urlParts[3];
$file = 'toread.txt';

header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: hack");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $file);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");
readfile($file);
echo md5(rand() . time());

?>
```

**toread.txt:**

> This is the content of toread.txt

Now using curl, I get the following results:

```
>curl -i http://example.com/test.php
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 04 Mar 2014 07:09:39 GMT
Server: Apache
Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate
Pragma: hack
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=toread.txt
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/force-download
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Connection: Keep-Alive
Age: 0

This is the content of toread.txt38d8a8009fad7315bdf5e823a06018e7
```

And the second one:

```
>curl -i http://example.com/test.php 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 04 Mar 2014 07:09:57 GMT
Server: Apache
Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate
Pragma: hack
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=toread.txt
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/force-download
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Connection: Keep-Alive
Age: 0

This is the content of toread.txt3b87356ea9ee007b70cfd619e31da950
```